# mp4 videos "do not play" on some devices when loaded in webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android

mp4 files not showing up in my emulator, they do show up on my real device.  The videos seem to play, but just show a blank space when they start. (on emulator)

Tried establishing that the videos are supported.  Tried a promise and a canPlayType on the page and wrote the results to a div.  According to those, it should be able to play the video.  (I do have gif versions of the same videos so I can swap them out on devices that cannot actually play them).

If autoplay is off, the video loads with a play button, and when I play it just turns blank.

.. Just a web view...

```
 <local:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView" Uri="https://mywebsite..." HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
```

Expected result would be to 1. play the video on all devices.  2. If I really can't play the video, let me swap it out for a gif or other version.  Or at the very least inform the user that the video is not supported or an error has occurred.

Is it just my emulator ? I am a beginner, this is my first ever project for Xamarin/Android other than samples.  Will the videos continue to work on other real devices but just a limitation of the emulator ?

Comment: Is this issue on iOS, Android or UWP? Or all? If Android, what emulator are you using (type and Android version it is running)? Most likely the issue is with the native platforms web view, i.e. WKWebView on iOS or WebView on Android, and what video types/codecs they support. I just tested a video page on 3 different versions of Android emulator (as I suspect that is most likely platform) and the video worked on all three emulators (Nougat, Pie and Oreo).

Comment: Here are the support video codecs for iOS and Android: https://support.paperlit.com/hc/en-us/articles/213670566-Android-iOS-Supported-Video-Format

Comment: So far I have only used android..  Was going to start working on iOS once I get this done.   The videos are H.264, should be supported.   The emulator is whatever the default emulator is that comes bundled with Visual Studio.   I am going to have to download some others and do some more testing.   It does work perfectly fine on my actual device...

Comment: I can't say what is happening. I did a quick test on 3 different emulator versions with a page that has a H.264 video, and it worked on all emulators. If you continue to have issues and want one on one support, you can open a free Xamarin support case here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6 . This would allow us to securely exchange code/urls, etc. privately.